# Could not find assembly Google.Api.Gax error when copying to server

Tags: google-api, reference, .net-assembly

I get the good ole "Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Api.Gax, Version=3.5.0.0" when trying to run a program from a server.

The scenario is this:
I have a .Net Solution in Visual Studio containing three projects basically:

- "Project One":  handles communication with Google PubSub and references all necessary assemblies (nuget) to manage the communication to PubSub
- "Project Two": A console application project which references "Project One" and is executed from a SQL Server.
- One is my testproject and also references "Project One" for testing purposes.

My testproject works fine and can execute all relevant methods in "Project One".
However, when I copy my console application to the SQL Server and make it execute I get the "Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Api.Gax, Version=3.5.0.0".
I can see that the file exists in the bin-folder of "Project Two" on the server but it is not of version 3.5.0.0. Instead it is of version 3.6.0 which is exactly the version it should be.

So I don't understand how/why it complains about not finding version 3.5.0.0 because that version of that assembly is never used.
I tried explicitly reference version 3.5.0.0 from "Project Two" to see what happend and then it complains about another of the google-api-assemblys being the wrong version.

What can I check more? I mean, the correct files are copied to the bin folder as far as I'm concerned..